# ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)

Tags: python-3.x

I try to pass a string to a website which check if there is any curse words.

I tried passing url to urlopen() and just like to document of urllib.request.urlopen(url, data), I tried passing the query string to data as well but couldn't achieve the result

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse

def read_text():
    quotes = open(r"D:\Courses\Udacity Full Stack Web Developer\Python 
Section\movie-quotes.txt")
    content_of_files = quotes.read()
    char_count = len(content_of_files)
    print(content_of_files)
    print(f"Total character count is {char_count}")
    quotes.close()
    check_profanity(content_of_files)

def check_profanity(text_to_check):
    url = "www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="
    connection = urllib.request.urlopen(url+text_to_check)
    print(connection.read())
    connection.close()

read_text()
```

```
ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: 'www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q=Houston, we have a problem. (Apollo 13)\n\nMama always said, life is like a box of chocolates. You never know what you are going to get. (Forrest Gump)\n\nYou cant handle the truth. (A Few Good Men)\n\nI believe everything and I believe nothing. (A Shot in the Dark)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the protocol part to the url.

Replace:

```
url = "www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="
```

with:

```
url = "http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="
```

Comment: thank, I tried this as well but got a new error

raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Comment: thanks for your time, I just add urllib.parse.quote(text_to_check) and got the result.