# Error raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)

Tags: python, debugging, web-scraping

I'm a beginner to python,I intend to learn python by working on projects,

I'm writing a script to scrape today's temperature from google search results, I got these lines of code from various website

here's my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen , Request
myurl="https://www.google.com/search?q=temperature+today"
req = Request(
myurl,
    data=None,
      headers={
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) >AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'    }
)
f = Request(req)
print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Produces an Error

```
raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: 'urllib.request.Request object at 0x004BF610'
```

## Note

MY assumption was `Request` is same as `urllib.request.urlopen`
because in the starting part, i had imported `urllib.request.urlopen` library as `Request`
Pl provide a reason as to why is it not the case

## Attempts to debug

So to debug this
instead of

```
f = Request(req)
print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

I wrote ( after req=.....)

```
print(req)
```

Tt gave an output

```
<urllib.request.Request object at 0x0023F610>
```

I'm unable to understand the error
Pl help me debug this

also Note-My question is different from this [ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56362584/valueerrorunknown-url-type-r-self-full-url)

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You are creating a `Request` object, but not using it to make a request. That is a low level interface. Try using `requests.get()` instead. https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.get

Comment: @baduker i didn't understand debugger message, so i posted and i have indeed tried to find the my mistake by meddling with different part of program and checking for output, all these attempts turned out to be futile, so I took help. The downvote was uncalled for

Comment: @Wodin could you pl elaborate your comment

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new Request object with the previous Request object as a parameter. Instead, you want to call `urlopen()` with your Request object. Like this:

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

myurl="https://www.google.com/search?q=temperature+today"
req = Request(
myurl,
    data=None,
      headers={
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) >AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'    
          })
f = urlopen(req)
print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: That worked,thanks a lot. I'm trying to learn coding in Python by doing projects,i copied that f variable assignment part from a site.

Comment: can you pl explain the first line of your answer, i'm unable to comprehend

Comment: req contains an Request object already. So calling `f=Request(req)` is like calling `f = Request(Request())`

Comment: isn't Request same as urlopen?

Comment: Well, [no](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request). But you can pass an url directly to urlopen, like this: `response = urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com")`

Comment: i thought Request is same as urllib.request.urlopen

Comment: i really appreciate your help,so what is significance of "," in "from urlllib.request import urlopen,Request". my understanding is that its similar to "fromurllib.request import urlopen as Request. Soby using comma, urlopen can be used interchangeably

Comment: turns out above assumption wrong,so what would be the right one

Comment: the comma in an import statement just imports both name from the same package.
`from X import A,B` is the same as
`from X import A;
from X import B`. Check [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/import.html) (python2, but the syntax is the same)